# Can't use Tomahawk in MyFaces 2.2

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jsf-2.2, myfaces, tomahawk

I am trying to use tags from the `Tomahawk` taglib in a Facelet of a project that uses MyFaces 2.2.12. The beginning of the Facelet looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
```

`Tomahawk` is included via `maven` in the `pom.xml` like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomahawk21</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now, when I use tags like `<t:panelGroup>` in my Facelet, my IDE (IntelliJ CE 2017 1.1) shows me the error

```
Cannot resolve symbol 't:panelGroup'
```

when I hover over the tag, even though it surely seems to [exist](https://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_panelGroup.html%20exist).

Just to make sure maven worked correctly I checked if the `Tomahawk` library is included in my `WEB-INF/lib` directory, and indeed, I find the file `tomahawk21-1.1.14.jar` there.

I also tried changing the namespace URI from `http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk` to `http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk21`, but this didn't have any effect.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Does your application actually work? Maybe the tomahawk taglib is just wrong for the ide

Comment: Yes, the application works. But tomahawk tags aren't rendered. What do you mean by "the tomahawk taglib is just wrong for the ide"? What does the IDE have to do with the used taglibs?

Comment: My last comment was wrong, tomahawk tags get indeed rendered, but the whole IDE is cluttered with "cannot resolve symbol" errors, making it very hard to spot actual errors.